# jsoup - get selected option from html select's options

Tags: jsoup

Does jsoup provide any way to get the selected option from an HTML select?

Something like jQuery's [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this:

```java
Elements selected = doc.select("select option[selected]");
```

Modify the first `select` part of the CSS query to winnow to the specific option container you need.

[Try it out](http://try.jsoup.org/~EjetqfbGQFct1cE3KwEGvjSiB60) with your HTML.